# HP EliteBook 8560w SATA compatibility

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, hp-elitebook

I know that **HP EliteBook 8560w/8570w** supports SATA III capable chipset. But this particular chipset has SATA III and SATA II capable channels.

I wonder which channel has HP used to connect the hard disk?

The thing is that I'm considering this notebook and I already have a new Samsung 830 256GB SSD that would be used to its maximum potential only on a SATA III channel.

#### So does HP EliteBook 85x0w connect hard disk over SATA III or SATA II channel?

Comment: That should be in the manual. May I suggest reading the fine manual?

Comment: @Hennes: As stated in the question I don't have the computer yet. I'm considering it. Which means I don't have the manual...

Comment: HP is a big brand. They have their manuals (as PDF) on their website.

Comment: @Hennes: In those PDFs I couldn't find any information about SATA II or SATA III. Just FYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13995_na/13995_na.HTML) doesn't say anything about supported SATA speeds...  As per the posts in the owners lounge [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-business-class-notebooks/581291-hp-elitebook-8560w-owners-lounge-53.html#post8153378)

```
port 0 and 1 are Sata 6Gbs, port 2 (eSATA on the dockingstation) is Sata 3GBs
```

Another mention of SATA III [here](http://dragonsgaming.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/hp-elitebook-8560-workstation/) where the owner actually tests a Crucial M4 in this machine.

Comment: Yes manual actually only mentions SATA 2... And that's what got me confused. Other links are better. Thanks. Seems this machine should be quite a beast. :)

Answer (score 5):

I ran the Passmark PerformanceTest 8.0 on my Elitebook 8560w, i7-2630qm, 8GB RAM with an Intel 330 series 180 GB SSD installed as the C: drive. Received 467MB/s for Read and 289MB/s Write. The write was surging between 150-410MB/s averaging the 289MB/s. The read was steady between 455-480MB/s averaging 467MB/s. I do not know why the performance surges during writes? It gives me the impression that the write performance has potential above the average if the surging can be reduced? Answering your question: yes, the internal drive ports 0 and 1 are SATA3 as is the eSATA. The advance docking station's ports are SATA2 only, including the docking stations drive bay.

Answer (score 0):

In the bios the sata 3gbs and 6gbs options are backwards, even in the latest bios, so don't bother updating it, just switch it to 3 gbs to get actually 6.